# Maximum Independent Subset of 2D Grid Subgraph

Tags: algorithm, graph

In the general case finding a Maximum Independent Subset of a Graph is NP Hard.

However consider the following subset of graphs:

Create an NxN grid of unit square cells.

Build a graph G by creating a vertex corresponding to every cell.  Notice that there are N^2 vertices.

Create an edge between two vertices if their cells share a side.  Notice there are 2N(N-1) edges.

A Maximum Independent Subset of G is obviously a checker pattern.  A cell at the Rth row and Cth column is part of it if R+C is odd.

Now we create a graph G' by copying G and removing some vertices and edges.  (If you remove a vertex also remove all edges it ended of course. Also note you can remove an edge without removing one of the vertices it ends.)

By what algorithm can we find a Maximum Independent Subset of G' ?

Comment: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3022/maximum-independent-subset-of-2d-grid-subgraph

Answer (score -1):

Read up [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_%28graph_theory%29#Finding_maximum_independent_sets).  I think you're still hosed, it remains NP-hard.

Since your degree is at most 4, the simple greedy algorithm obtains an approximation ratio of 2.  Your resulting graph is also planar, so there is a good approximation algorithm (any fixed approximation ratio in poly time).

Comment: Its not NP-hard.  It may be true that planar and degree 4 are not sufficient on their own, but it is also a grid subgraph.  The fact that it is a grid subgraph leads to an efficient solution.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos-Fathomling: which is?

Comment: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3022/maximum-independent-subset-of-2d-grid-subgraph